# Is GC drawing on top of an SWT_AWT Bridged frame possible?

Tags: java, swt, awt

I am trying to do something of this sort with no luck.

Composite c = new Composite(shell);
JFrame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(c);
**GC gc = new GC(c);

c.fillRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);**

code runs fine but I can't get the rectangle to show on top. I think the frame hides it. Is there a way to put the GC drawings on top?

Thanks,

-Hadi

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in SWT, transparency is not possible. There are some options available that might lead you to think they're built for this effect but all they do does is either not render say the canvas background or render it using alpha value without rendering the composites bellow it. In other words, SWT doesn't allow you to have see through components.